# Avoiding SQL deadlock in insert combined with select

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, database-deadlocks

I'm trying to insert pages into a table with a sort column that I auto-increment by 2000 in this fashion:

```
INSERT INTO pages (sort,img_url,thumb_url,name,img_height,plank_id)
SELECT IFNULL(max(sort),0)+2000,'/image/path.jpg','/image/path.jpg','name',1600,'3'
FROM pages WHERE plank_id = '3'
```

The trouble is I trigger these inserts on the upload of images, so 5-10 of these queries are run almost simultaneously. This triggers a deadlock on some files, for some reason.

Any idea what is going on?

Edit: I'm running MySQL 5.5.24 and InnoDB. The sort column has an index.

Comment: For some reason? Almost certainly because of the select max.

Comment: is there an index on the sort column?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: is `sort` unique - could it be made an auto-increment column?  Why don't you store the image width as well as the height?

Comment: @MartinSmith I believe I'm running MySQL 5.5.24

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse sort should be unique, yes, but PhpMyAdmin does not allow me to set sort to auto increment, since the id column is already auto incremented.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No index on sort. plank_id is the only column that relates to another table.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I'd still avoid this design myself, but an index on sort my alleviate some of the symptoms.

Comment: @Timur InnoDB it seems, but I can't say it was a concious choice, that was just the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

What I made for myself is setting `sort` to `0` on insert, retrieve `id` of inserted row and set `sort` to `id*2000`. But, also, you can try to use transactions:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO pages (sort,img_url,thumb_url,name,img_height,plank_id)
SELECT IFNULL(max(sort),0)+2000,'/image/path.jpg','/image/path.jpg','name',1600,'3'
FROM pages WHERE plank_id = '3';
COMMIT;
```

Note that not all of the MySQL client libraries support multiqueris, so you may have to execute them separately but in stream of one connection.

Another approach is to lock the whole table for the time `INSERT` is executed, but this will lead to increase of queries queue because they will have to wait until insert is performed